# Adding an image to the first item in a listview?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have created a listview which pulls the scores of users held in a database.

For the person who is number one I would like to add a small image of a star but I am confused as to how I would go about this???

so far my code is as follows

```
            var data = from x in db.DT_BenchScores
                   where x.Enabled == true
                   orderby x.Max_Bench descending, x.Date descending
                   select new
                   {
                       x.ScoreID,
                       x.Alias,
                       Bench = x.Max_Bench + "kg",
                   };

        LV_Scores.DataSource = data.Take(20);
        LV_Scores.DataBind();
```

I would like to add the following next to the first person

```
<span class="fr"><img src="_includes/images/no1.jpg" /></span>
```

Can someone please explain how I would do this???

Many Thanks

Comment: This is presumably ASP.NET? Or is it winforms or WPF?

Comment: You can find example here ... How to add images to list view using asp.net .. this link will shows adding images to list view using vb.net and c# also .... http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ItemDataBound` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) to respond *each time* an item is bound from a database row.  In this event handler, you can access the `ListViewItem` that is being created, and modify it as needed.

**EDIT**

See this CodeProject post for a sample: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ItemCreated.aspx?msg=1540986